# Should I keep using Swing for my desktop application

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am currently working on an application with a code base that dates back to at least 2001.  One of the components of this system is a desktop client that is written using Java Swing.  It uses most of the good old layouts including BorderLayout, FlowLayout, and Gridbag layout.  There are a number of fairly complex screens we need to manage and update periodically and we sometimes need to create new features with new user interfaces.

Is there something better than Swing we could look into migrating to?

Would it be possible to do this migration in stages (i.e. we would have a mix of the old Swing components with the new components during a prolonged migration phase)?

If we were to re-write the desktop client in Java today should we still use Swing?

I find myself using primarily GridBagLayout, is this still the tool of choice for more complex layouts or are there better layouts I could be using?

Comment: Don't use an IDE to generate the layout code. Then you are locked into the IDE. Instead use the appropriate combination of layout managers to get your desired layout. The is you can nest panel with different layouts into a parent panel. This allows you to logically create panels with the appropriate layout for each panel.

Comment: The question you really need to be asking is, is it worth the effort. Is there some feature (like better html support or media support) which your apps really needs? If not, maintaining the code base in Swing isn't a bad choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was reading in book that Oracle intend to replace Swing by JavaFX.

Take a look in the question and answer bellow:

> **6. Is JavaFX replacing Swing as the new client UI library for Java SE?**
>   Yes. However, Swing will remain part of the Java SE specification for the foreseeable future, and therefore included in the JRE. While we recommend developers to leverage JavaFX APIs as much as possible when building new applications, it is possible to extend a Swing application with JavaFX, allowing for a smoother transition.

You can see there original comment [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6).

In this case, I believe that you can consider to user [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html).

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) and good examples [here](http://fxexperience.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8 you can use javafx for new componant. It's possible to use Swing componant with javafx.

Comment: Does JavaFX requires java 8?

Comment: No it can be used with java 7 but the last version is included with java 8

Answer (score 1):

you can still use java swing, but if you need to migrate you can migrate in stages using JavaFX (again a Desktop Client). if you need to use Web Client, then you could use GWT (this helps since the developers already have knowlege of UI Components) and GWT code is in Java and Javascript gets generated in Compile Time.

Answer (score 1):

- Java FX is more powerful and beautiful
- We can say that swing is replaced with java FX.
- Now a days no body is using swing because there are lot of advantage in java FX over swing
- It has good feature  called scaneBuilder we can just drag and drop the components to appropriate position so lot of time is saving.
- Different type of layout are there to place the components attractively.
- Impertinently **we can use CSS** to disign the UI so is more beautiful and attractive
- we can integrate with web components also.

Comment: *"and beautiful" that's a matter of opinion - I have clients who would argue against that; *"Now a days no body is using swing"* - I see more Swing based jobs then JavaFX jobs; *"It has good feature called scaneBuilder "* great ANOTHER form editor, because that was never a problem :P; *"Different type of layout are there to place the components attractively"* 8| ... I take it you never learnt to use a layouts manager properly then (or creatively) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're redoing a layout entirely, I'd look at Matisse which uses Spring Layout.

https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html

It's far easier to get the relationships between components using a layout tool than trying to line everything up manually in GridBag or something similar.

If you're not redoing a major part of the code, I wouldn't touch it.  Don't fix what ain't broken.

Regarding JavaFX, I personally have not been impressed by it.  You can take a look at it, but JavaFX struck me as needing more "bake" time.  I would not abandon Swing just yet.

Comment: I do prefer JFormDesigner. It is much easier to use than Matisse.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a Java desktop client looks like native application for some platform (Windows, MacOS, Linux) you can look on [Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT) library](https://www.eclipse.org/swt).

One famous application example of usage of this library is [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/ide). Another - [Angry IP Scan](http://angryip.org), [sources are](https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan) at GitHub.